# Application Caching on iPad will not cache website data or pages

Tags: html, ipad, .htaccess, caching, manifest

I am running a DHTML page and want to cache the HTML, PHP file and IMAGE files that are referenced.

I have all the following files in WWW.sitename.COM/sub-dir/

.htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

cache.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Cache manifest version 0.0.00002

NETWORK:

CACHE:

http://WWW.sitename.COM/sub-dir/index.html
http://WWW.sitename.COM/sub-dir/this.php
http://WWW.sitename.COM/sub-dir/images/first.png
http://WWW.sitename.COM/sub-dir/images/second.png

FALLBACK:
```

HTML manifest reference in THIS.PHP file...

```
<html manifest="http://WWW.sitename.COM/sub-dir/cache.manifest">
```

script to detect cache activity

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cacheStatusValues = [];
cacheStatusValues[0] = 'uncached';
cacheStatusValues[1] = 'idle';
cacheStatusValues[2] = 'checking';
cacheStatusValues[3] = 'downloading';
cacheStatusValues[4] = 'updateready';
cacheStatusValues[5] = 'obsolete';

var cache = window.applicationCache;
cache.addEventListener('cached', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('checking', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('downloading', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('error', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('noupdate', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('obsolete', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('progress', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('updateready', logEvent, false);

function logEvent(e) 
{
var online, status, type, message;
online = (navigator.onLine) ? 'yes' : 'no';
status = cacheStatusValues[cache.status];
type = e.type;
message = 'online: ' + online;
message+= ', event: ' + type;
message+= ', status: ' + status;
if (type == 'error' && navigator.onLine) 
{
    message+= ' (probably a syntax error in cache.manifest)';
}
console.log(message);
}



window.applicationCache.addEventListener(
'updateready',
function(){
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
    console.log('swap cache has been called');
},
false
);

setInterval(function(){cache.update()}, 10000);

</script>
```

The console reports that nothing is being cached.

Any and all assistance gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried removing the absolute path in the HTML tag and replacing it with <html manifest="cache.manifest"> as suggested on other sites, and rebuilding the manifest file. None of these have had any effect. The console reports "this.php (line 1603)

online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached

this.php (line 1603)
"

Comment: Firebug Console  

online: yes, event: checking, status: uncached  

online: yes, event: downloading, status: uncached  

online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached  

online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached

online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached  

online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached  

online: yes, event: updateready, status: uncached  

InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
 
window.applicationCache.swapCache();

online: yes, event: checking, status: uncached

online: yes, event: noupdate, status: uncached

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much research the answer is...

1. DO NOT include the names of the pages that hold the

   html manifest="cache.manifest"

   tag in the cache.manifest file.
2. Ensure the cache.manifest file only uses relative URLs not ABSOLUTE.
3. Ensure your iPad had been rebooted AT LEAST once after any system software update.
4. The correct MIME type for the manifest file in the .htaccess file is

   AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

Thanks to Bjorn at dev.bjorn.com/723 for helping me get there... a good blog post worth reading.

Comment: ALSO - as a not to others with this issue - ensure your text editor is saving the cache.manifest file as ANSI standard TXT - not UTF-8 or UNICODE. I was just tinkering and tried a few formats. only ANSI TXT works.

Comment: Also, open up the console in Chrome and it will tell you about errors downloading the cache.  I'm not sure if some errors prevents ALL caching, but it might.

Comment: I've just confirmed that some errors prevent ALL caching.  For example, if your cache points to a url that returns a 404, nothing will be cached.  And here's a #5 for you: Your urls can't have spaces in them.  Replace each space with a "%20"